# How link multiple keys to the same value in the HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, hyperlink, hashmap, key

I am trying to link the value of a key to another key's value but cannot seem to get it working.

For example, if I'm creating a `HashMap` and adding a key-value pair `("x", 0)` to it. I then want to be able to add *other keys* mapped to the same value as the first one.

So if I have `("x", map.get("y"))` and `("y", 0)` I want to be able somehow to link it. So that if I now update a value for `"y"` key like that `("y", 10)`, then I expect that `map.get("x")` should also return `10`.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("x", 0);
map.put("y", 0);

//I now somehow want to link the value of x so its dependent on y

System.out.println(map.get("x"));
//Should return 0

map.put("y", 10);

System.out.println(map.get("x"));
//Should return 10 now
```

I can't figure out how to get this working as x always gets the value of what y is now, and not what y is at the time of printing the value.

Comment: Either write your own implementation of  a map class that extends HashMap and override the put method or don't use the put method to modify your map but write your own update method.

Comment: What happens if you do map.put(“z”,20) after putting y? Do all gets give you 20 in that case?

Comment: @Eritrean how would I go about that? Could you perhaps give me an example on what such a method could look like?

Comment: @RichardKYu if I do map.put("z", 20); after putting y i would like to x-value to be the same as y-value and z to be its own value. I want to be able to choose which values are linked and not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to associate a group of *keys* with the *same object*, it can be achieved by using a **mutable object** as a value.

For instance, you can make use of `StringBuilder` or implement a custom class. It'll be more **performant** and **easier** than an approach with implementing your own map which extends `HashMap` and is able to track these groups of keys and triggers a series of updates for each call of `put()`, `replace()` or `remove()`.

Solution with a custom mutable `Container` can look like this:

```
HashMap<String, Container<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
Container<Integer> commonValue = new Container<>(0);
map.put("x", commonValue);
map.put("y", commonValue);

System.out.println("Value for 'x': " + map.get("x"));
System.out.println("Value for 'y': " + map.get("y"));

commonValue.setValue(10);

System.out.println("Value for 'x': " + map.get("x"));
System.out.println("Value for 'y': " + map.get("y"));
```

The `Container` class itself.

```
public class Container<T> {
    private T value;

    public Container(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
}
```

As I have already said, the alternative is to use a mutable class that is already provided by the JDK. The code is then almost the same:

```
HashMap<String, StringBuilder> map = new HashMap<>();
StringBuilder commonValue = new StringBuilder("0");
map.put("x", commonValue);
map.put("y", commonValue);

System.out.println("Value for 'x': " + map.get("x"));
System.out.println("Value for 'y': " + map.get("y"));

commonValue.replace(0, commonValue.length(), "10");

System.out.println("Value for 'x': " + map.get("x"));
System.out.println("Value for 'y': " + map.get("y"));
```

Output (by both versions)

```
Value for 'x': 0
Value for 'y': 0
Value for 'x': 10
Value for 'y': 10
```

Comment: In this case, I think I would opt for `HashMap<String, int[]>`, where each value is an array of length one.

Comment: @VGR I don't feel like mixing arrays and generics is a good idea even for such a simple case.

Comment: @VGR And code like that `map.get("x")[0]` doesn't look nice, it resembles *javascript*. I think `map.get("x").getValue()` is more easier to read.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!